What is the name of this literary pattern used by Shakespeare?
In the balcony scene from Shakespeare's Romeo and Juliet, Juliet says:

O Romeo, Romeo! wherefore art thou Romeo?

This is an almost identical structure to this line from Richard III:

A horse, a horse, my kingdom for a horse!

Ignoring the initial "O" in Juliet's line, you have two syllables repeated at the start of the sentence and again at the end.
Is there a name for this literary pattern?
I cannot remember the source in which I read it, but I believe that this is a well-known structure that was known to classical writers of Greece and Rome and that it is one of many such patterns that were used by Shakespeare and continue to be used by writers today.

"Romeo" is three syllables.

My fairly uneducated answer (explained below) is that it’s unlikely we’ll find a specific name for that pattern in Classical Greek verse, because to my knowledge the Classical Greeks were not known for their use of alliteration. In this case, my citation is the lack of citations.
That said, I think this question requires some novel research, so I may update my answer later if I uncover more.

With verse, we can analyze either the content or the rhythm. In this case we must analyze the rhythm. The two components of rhythm we will consider are meter and alliterative verse:
Meter

Classical Greeks formalized the art and science of poetic rhythm as prosody.
Meter is one representation of prosody, describing a verse’s rhythm by syllabic flow and stress. Specifically, it defines any given line of verse as a foot (cluster of high and low syllables), repeated n times.
Shakespeare is the most famous user of iambic pentameter, where iamb is the specific name of the foot that goes (baDUM, i.e. _-, i.e. a heartbeat), and penta is Ancient Greek for five.
So, most of Shakespeare’s verse (including the examples you gave) go: baDUM baDUM baDUM baDUM baDUM.

Alliteration

Your question considers both the meter and the melody of the prosody, i.e. not just the stresses but also the sounds of the syllables.
The topic you’re looking for is alliterative verse
You are asking about a very specific pattern:

_A_A_-_-_A


This is where I (and you if you’re interested) can dig more to see if this scheme appears in Classical Greek poetry, and if so, whether it has a name.
In general, while a lot of Germanic poetic tradition descends from the Classical Greek / Latin branch of poetry, we see much more alliteration in English poetry than in that of our Greek predecessors. That’s why I’m a bit doubtful that I’ll find an answer for this.

I know it’s not the most satisfying answer, but I enjoyed writing it up, and while I am betting you already know a lot of the above, I hope that the formal structure / vocabulary above was useful.

From your question, you seem to be interested in the use of Repetition in the line in question.  I think you must be referring to the rhetorical device known as anaphora (αναφορα), which is, in fact, simply Greek for repetition from 'ανα (ana)', meaning 'again' and phora, the abstract noun from 'phero (φερω)' meaning 'I carry/bear'. So the Greek term means repetion. Anaphora, of course, intensifies.
You might wonder whether the Greek term is a better description of this rhetorical/theatrical feature than the English 'repetition'.
At the same time, of course, Juliet's opening exclamation stretches the stage iambic pentameter (in a good way). Giving 'Romeo' its full three syllables, the iambic pentameter finds itself with not ten but fourteen syllables. You can cut it down a bit by pronouncing 'Romeo' as 'Romyo', which gets it down to eleven syllables, which was the hendekasyllable metre used famously by the great Lesbic poetess, Sappho, except with a very different rhythm (tum ti tum tum tum ti ti tum ti tum tum).  Even so, Juliet's line reads more like a trochaic than an iambic line with a sigh at the beginning.

Can you add a dictionary definition, please. The first two I checked in state that Anaphora is a subset of repetition.

@Edwin Ashworth Thank you for waking me up.  'Anaphora' is, in fact a subset of repetition and, now you mention  it, the wrong subset.  It is, as I was aware, mostly used for repetition, namely the same word/phrase in different sentences rather than in the same sentence.  The term for "Tiger, tiger, burning bright" type repetition  in the same sentence that my rusty old brain failed to recall is 'anadiplosis'.  I shall now make the due correction.  Would you please doc me the point to set the record straight?
